# can we burn algorithm built on labview in dsp kit tms320c6713?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, labview

i'm working on a project "real-time audio encryption using aes-256 on tms320c6713". in this project, i'll be continuously taking the voice from the microphone and continuously implementing advanced encryption standard-256 on the voice, and continuously transmitting that encrypted signal to some other point using a radio transmitter. and then at the receiver's side; the decryption process would take place.

i want to ask that, can we burn the algorithm built on labview on the dsp kit?
because there's a aes library in labview which can help in making my task easier. my initial plan is to design that algorthm using labview and then burn that code diirectly on my dsk. would it be possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

National Instruments used to have a DSP Module for LabVIEW that targeted this board.

I think it is no longer supported, and is likely not compatible with the latest versions of LabVIEW.

See here:

http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/201839

Comment: ok thanks.. also i want to ask that is there any dsp kit that has built-in aes-256 library? if you know anything about it, do let me know..

Comment: I think that would be a new question... possibly at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/